# Oracle SQL, Select and compare dates against null values

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I need to select and compare the last advertised date in advert, to any null values in lease to get when an un-leased property and when it was last advertised. This is the code I have so far;

```
SELECT YR_LEASE.PROPERTYNUM, 
       MAX(YR_ADVERT.DATETO),
 count(YR_LEASE.RENTERNUM)      
FROM YR_LEASE
JOIN YR_ADVERT
    ON YR_LEASE.PROPERTYNUM=YR_ADVERT.PROPERTYNUM
GROUP BY YR_LEASE.PROPERTYNUM
```

This returns a count this is far too high and I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong, here's my ERD to try and give this question some context;

http://www.gliffy.com/pubdoc/4239520/L.png

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to first identify unleased properties. From there you can find the latest advert date. Assuming some properties have never been advertised you'll need to go via YR_PROPERTY and do a left join to include unadvertised properties.

```
SELECT NVL(TO_CHAR(MAX(YR_ADVERT.DATETO),'DD/MM/YYYY'),'NO LAST ADVERT DATE') LAST_ADVERT_DATE
      ,YR_PROPERTY.PROPERTYNUM      
FROM YR_PROPERTY LEFT JOIN YR_ADVERT ON YR_PROPERTY.PROPERTYNUM = YR_ADVERT.PROPERTYNUM
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM  YR_LEASE 
                  WHERE YR_LEASE.PROPERTYNUM = YR_PROPERTY.PROPERTYNUM
                  AND   YR_LEASE.RENT_FINISH > SYSDATE)
GROUP BY YR_LEASE.PROPERTYNUM;
```